# When i try to submit form without data, it shows the validation error with controller create action view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: This is the error message displayed]

I tried to validates the text field but got the above error. The code of the controller is:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @reimbursements = @user.reimbursements.new(reimbursements_params)
    if @reimbursements.save!
      flash[:success] = "Reimbursement successfully created."
      redirect_to user_reimbursements_path
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
      redirect_to new_user_reimbursement_path, info: "message display garni"
    end
   end
```

Comment: You should probably paste the code for `reimbursements_params` and the json sent to the server too.

Comment: There must be a validation in reimbursement model to make sure description and amount are provided during create. Make sure you pass them in reimbursements_params...I see that you are not passing any description or amount in your params

Comment: In addition to what the others have said (`reimbursements_params` and the JSON sent to the server), it sounds like there might be some form validation on the client that is not working? If that's the case and that's what you're asking for help with, that should be posted as well. Otherwise, `save!` will throw an error if it fails and `save` will simply return `false`. Currently looks like you might want it to be returning false, not erring out.

Answer (score 3):

You must remove the exclamatory mark from save in the controller method

Use only

```
if @reimbursements.save
```

This will return true or false and so it goes to the else part when the validations fail. Adding the ! to save will throw validation errors in controller.

You can check the following link for further information https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save%21

Comment: Just what I was typing in the comments for them, although maybe link them to [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) instead of the Rails 2.3 one which links off to 4 possible others